# ambiguous reference for foreign key data anotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, ambiguous

i have class like the following

```
public class Privilege 
{

    [ForeignKey("User")] // error line
    public int? UserId { get; set; }


    ....
}
```

everything was fine until i change the target framework of the project. it was .Net 4.0 and i changed it to 4.5

now there is an error for ForeignKey("User") part.

The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists in both 
'c:....\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'

how should i solve this issue?

by the way as you can easily understand i m using entity framework in my project and its version 6.1.1

Comment: This question was [answered before on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17791989/997668).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type definition exists in two libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791930/type-definition-exists-in-two-libraries)